# MariaDB 10.1 and MySQL2 gem with rails on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, mariadb

I can't run my Rails 4.2/MariaDB app on Ubuntu 14.04.
I installed MariaDB 10.1.9.

```
apt-get install software-properties-common
apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 0xcbcb082a1bb943db
add-apt-repository 'deb [arch=amd64,i386] http://ftp.igh.cnrs.fr/pub/mariadb/repo/10.1/ubuntu trusty main'
apt-get update
apt-get install mariadb-server
```

Also the client:

```
apt-get install libmariadbclient-dev
```

MariaDB is working great.

But the MySQL2 gem doesn't work:

I installed it with:

```
gem uninstall mysql2
```

gem install mysql2 -v='0.3.18' -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/bin/mysql_config

```
Fetching: mysql2-0.3.18.gem (100%)
Building native extensions with: '--with-mysql-config=/usr/bin/mysql_config'
This could take a while...
Successfully installed mysql2-0.3.18
1 gem installed
```

It works. I opened the mysql_config file and it contains the 10.1.9 version.

But when I deploy my app, I have this "classical" error:

```
Incorrect MySQL client library version! This gem was compiled for 5.5.46 but the client library is 10.1.9-MariaDB.
```

but I compiled it for MariaDB 10.1.9 !!!

In addition, note that I have installed also "libmysqlclient18" before "libmariadbclient-dev"... don't know if this can be a problem.

Thanks

Comment: I removed my deployed app (with capistrano). I installed once again the mysql2 gem, then I add the mysql2 config to bundler config, and launch a new deployment... and it works.